# Why is it wrong to use the binomial to obtain the power series about a point from the power series of about another point?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, power-series

I am following Serge Lang's Introduction to Complex Analysis at a graduate level and I have a question in regards to method I used in one of the exercises. The exercise was to find the Laurent series about $z=1$ of the function $$f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2+1}.$$

I thought that I do the following

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-z^2)^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n((z-1+1)^2)^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^{2n}{}(z-1)^k \binom{2n}{k} $$

and after a bit of a simification

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(z-1)^n\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{n}(-1)^k,$$

for $|z|<1.$ However, this does not seem to be right as first my answer differents from the one in the solutions (where the author used partial fraction decomposition), and moreover, I believe there are issues with the convergenece of the coeficients that I have derived.

Could somebody explain to me/ guide me to understanding the error in my methodology?

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n$ does not exist.

Comment: It fails because $1$ is on the boundary of the disk of convergence of $\sum_{n\ge 0} (-z^2)^n$. When $a$ is inside the disk it works fine. @JoshuaWang